# Reduce image palette to the actual colors

Tags: gif, palette, linux

I made this image:

[image: Gimp gif]

And now I need to save it to Gif, but no matter what I try I end up with an image containing **only two colors**.

How can I properly reduce the palette of my image to the actual number (apparently no more that a dozen shades of grey) it contains? I tried imagemagick's `convert` too, but it produces a nasty blur, actually *adding* colors :/

Comment: The GIF format doesn't support semi transparency.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simply that all your pixels are in fact the same *color* (white), they just have different *transparency*.

A GIF only has *1-bit* transparency. A pixel is either 100% opaque or 100% transparent. So it's not possible to save a GIF preserving these semi-transparent pixels.

The solution would be to save a PNG-24 instead as it supports *8-bit* transparency.

Alternatively, if the image is always to be shown on same background color, you can add the background color to the image and save it as a GIF without transparency.